# Signature verification - machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, classification, image-classification

I have to do a project on signature verification. 
My goal is having a program with two images as inupt (one is a genuine signature of a selected subject and the other one is the one that I want to test).
I have a dataset to train the algorithm with 3000 signatures: half of them are genuine and the other ones are forgery, and they are taken from 150 subjects.

My doubt regards the confrontation between the two images I use as input (the genuine one and the one I want to test).
How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a Siamese Network is the solution you are looking for. [Arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.02131) has a paper which precisely addresses your problem.